# How to set up nginx upstream to check response and set this server to 'down' when response is a 40x

Tags: node.js, nginx

I have three servers. All three use nginx 1.10.3. Two of these servers also host a nodejs application which is only listening on port 2403. The corresponding nginx-instances serve these nodejs apps via port 80. The third server deals as a load balancer and does a simple round robin via upstream to these other two servers.

As far as I know when one of the upstream-servers is down nginx removes these servers from the upstream and does health-checks every n seconds. If the server is back online it's readded.

But now I have the following situation:

One of the nodejs applications crashes. The nginx-instance is still running and listenes on port 80. The nginx-loadbalancer checks port 80, gets a response and therefore continues with the round-robin (but the app isn't reachable of course). Now I would like to setup nginx that, for example, it checks the response of the upstream and when there is a header (there should be a 403/503 header, shouldn't it?) it removes the broken/down server and only uses the last one till it's working again.

How can I do that?

I can provide the nginx configs if you like.

Comment: did you try match in your Nginx?
browse this:
[nginx health check](https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/http-health-check/#hc_active)

Comment: Using health_check; is only available in NGINX Plus. Passive Health Checks are working, see https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/http-health-check/ Problem is that the default health checks should work because nginx listens on that port but the application to which nginx should redirect to (nodejs app) isn't running.